# Check user input on "rm -i"?

Tags: bash, rm

Is there a way to check the user's response to a `rm -i` execution?
I'd like to `echo` something depending on whether or not the user responded with `y` or `n`.

The command returns successfully regardless of the user's response, so this attempt did not work:

```
$ rm -i testfile.txt && echo "The file was deleted."
remove testfile.txt? n
The file was deleted.
```

My reasoning was that the `echo` part would only be executed if the `rm` part was successful, but obviously a `n` response also counts as successful execution.

I would also like to be able to vary the message depending on the answer. This code would do it, but it's not very pretty.

```sh
file=testfile.txt
touch $file

read -p "Are you sure (y/n)? " answer
if [[ $answer =~ ^[yY](es|ES)?$ ]]; then
    rm $file
    echo "Deleted file."
else
    echo "Did nothing."
fi
```

Surely there must be a way to get the input to `rm -i`. 
How?

Comment: Unfortunately no, at least GNU rm does not give you fine grain error reporting through returns.  I think @Dzienny has a reasonably good answer.  However it becomes hairy with multiple files.  Your approach may also be dictated by the specific usecase you're trying to solve, can you expand on that a bit?

Comment: @AhmedMasud My program is looping through a list of (big) files, and for each file the user is asked whether [s]he wants to delete, compress or ignore the file. The result is written to a log file (i.e. `echo "$file was [deleted|compressed|ignored]" >> logfile.txt`). So, if the user chooses to delete, I want to confirm with `rm -i`, and if a negative answer is given, the file is ignored instead. Hope this made my goal clearer. Thanks for responding!

Comment: pluse-uno for excellent first Q: formatted, code, [mcve], everthing! Keep posting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check, if the file was actually deleted. Eg.

```
rm -i testfile.txt && [[ ! -e testfile.txt ]] && echo "The file was deleted."
```

If the `rm` is successful, then test, if the file does not exist `[[ ! -e file ]]` and only then display the message. It covers the case, when you try to remove the file that does not exist, since then the `rm` will return with the exit code different than 0.

In case you want to display messages for when the file was purposefully deleted or not deleted, plus extra info on error, then you can extend the previous code like so:

```
rm -i testfile.txt && {
    [[ ! -e testfile.txt ]] && echo "The file was deleted." || echo "Ignored"
} || echo "Error"
```

Comment: Thank you! I built on your answer with this: `rm -i testfile.txt; if [[ ! -e testfile.txt) ]]; then echo "Deleted."; else echo "Ignored."; fi`, and it worked as I wanted!

Comment: @genbatro I extended the answer for this case.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the problem with your attempt is that you are trying to accommodate too many possible inputs, or paradoxically *limiting* the input to specifically "yes" or "no" while excluding "yeah", "yup", "nope", etc. A simply `y` or `n` will do (in fact, the only distinction you need to make is between `y` and not-`y`).

```
read -p "Are you sure (y/n)? " answer
if [[ $answer = [yY]* ]]; then
    rm -- "$file"
    echo "Deleted file."
else
    echo "Did nothing."
fi
```

If you like, you can use `shopt -s nocasematch` before the `if` statement so that you can simply write `if [[ $answer = y* ]]; then` to ignore the case of the user's actual input.

Your original question would require some hook provided by `rm` itself, which it does not do.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Those are great tips.